# How do I use Qt's "Graphics View" framework from python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, pyside2

Background: I'm trying to make a VR demo in python using the Qt Graphics View framework, which allows custom rendered GUIs. I have the option of two different python modules that wrap Qt: `PyQt5` and `PySide2`. Unfortunately each of these modules seems to be missing a different key ingredient in the Graphics View Framework.

`PyQt5` seems to be missing a constructor for `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`, which is needed for creating synthetic mouse events from the VR controller gestures. This brief PyQt5 program...

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QPointF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QOpenGLPaintDevice  # No problem for PyQt5

pos = QPointF(20, 20)
event1 = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseMove, pos, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
device = QOpenGLPaintDevice(100, 100)

# Problem: TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
event2 = QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent(QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseMove)
```

...results in `TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent cannot be instantiated or sub-classed`

The seemingly good news is that the alternate Qt-binding `PySide2` module can construct a `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` without complaint. But `PySide2` is missing the QOpenGLPaintDevice class, which I need for actually drawing the widget. This very similar program, which uses PySide2...

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent, QPointF, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent

pos = QPointF(20, 20)
event1 = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseMove, pos, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
event2 = QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent(QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseMove)  # No Problem for PySide2

from PySide2.QtGui import QOpenGLPaintDevice  # Problem: PySide2 does not have this class
device = QOpenGLPaintDevice(100, 100)
```

results in `ImportError: cannot import name 'QOpenGLPaintDevice'`

I'm not sure anyone has ever successfully used the Qt Graphics View framework from python. If not, I'd like to be the first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is not a bug that QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent is not enabled in PyQt5 but it is a bug that is enabled in PySide2 since if you review [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html) it is observed that QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent does not have a public constructor.

If you want to emulate mouse movements in a Qt Graphics Framework then you must send QMouseEvent to the [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) of the QGraphicsView.

In the following example I show how to move an item by emulating the mouse using QMouseEvent:

```py
from functools import partial
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 400, 400), self)
        self.m_graphicsview = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.m_scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.m_graphicsview)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.m_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(QtCore.QRectF(-50, -50, 100, 100))
        self.m_item.setFlags(
            self.m_item.flags() | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
        )
        self.m_item.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("salmon"))
        self.m_item.setPos(100, 100)
        self.m_scene.addItem(self.m_item)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.emulate_move_item)

    def emulate_move_item(self):
        sp = self.m_item.mapToScene(self.m_item.boundingRect().center())
        lp = self.m_graphicsview.mapFromScene(sp)
        end_pos = lp + QtCore.QPoint(100, 100)

        self.press(lp)

        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            startValue=lp,
            endValue=end_pos
        )
        animation.valueChanged.connect(self.moveTo)
        animation.finished.connect(partial(self.release, end_pos))
        animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    def press(self, pos):
        event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
            pos,
            self.m_graphicsview.mapToGlobal(pos),
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self.m_graphicsview.viewport(), event)

    def moveTo(self, pos):
        event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove,
            pos,
            self.m_graphicsview.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos),
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self.m_graphicsview.viewport(), event)

    def release(self, pos):
        event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
            pos,
            self.m_graphicsview.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos),
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self.m_graphicsview.viewport(), event)

    def double_click(self, pos):
        event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            pos,
            self.m_graphicsview.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos),
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self.m_graphicsview.viewport(), event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In conclusion:

- The QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent constructor must not be enabled in python since it is not accessible in the public API of Qt in C++. So the behavior of PyQt5 is correct, but PySide2 has a bug.
- That PySide2 does not have the QOpenGLPaintDevice class implemented is a possible bug.

Comment: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent constructor works in my C++ version of the demo, so it's constructor must be public. Or are you using the word "public" in a different way to me?

Comment: Thank you for the example. It might take me a few days for me to fully evaluate it.

Comment: @ChristopherBruns You could show me the C ++ code that you are referring to, I have reviewed the docs: https://i.imgur.com/Y8NzpsK.png, and I do not see the constructor method so I presume that it is a private constructor. Do you understand what the concept of public, protected and private refers to in C++? the binding only exposes the public and protected methods.

Comment: @ellyanesc Public declaration of QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent constructor:
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/53d62b8fcbb639bd625777c8f1c01764445fb1c4/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicssceneevent.h#L67
Working C++ code using constructor:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/samples/helloworldoverlay/openvroverlaycontroller.cpp#L213

Comment: @ChristopherBruns I find it strange, maybe it's a bug from the docs, I'm going to do an investigation.